# Is it able to set Favorites repo in VS or Web with TFS2015?

Tags: tfs

We are working with multiple projects and repos simultaneously. Need a feature to set Favorites or tag repo in VS or Web with TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not support to add a tag like 'favorite' for repositories in TFS in TFS web page and VS 2015.

As a workaround, in VS 2017, it supports to remove those repositories you don't need and only keep one repository. Maybe you could try to use VS 2017.

[image]

Here is an user voice about your request and you could add comment and vote here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19053559-set-a-default-favoriate-repository

Comment: Instead of removing, are there something like hidden or depreciate the repos?